# Java based opensource VNC application or library

Tags: java, cuda, opencl, gpu, vnc

Is there any active Java remote desktop application including sourcecode or a library for integrating into Java applictions?

The problem is that ultravnc, realvnc and tightvnc are not available (opensource) for Java, just sometimes a viewer.

It should be in plain Java code so it runs on all platforms.

edit: It might not be possible to make it just with Java, but in times of better GPUs and CPUs it might be better to use some libraries which add support for multithreading, like CUDA, OpenCL and Rootbeer (https://github.com/pcpratts/rootbeer1)

Comment: What is keeping you from write a Applet or an Swing-Client?

Comment: It needs to be added to a desktop application (no browser application or applet) and need client + server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody ever tried to implement a VNC server in Java because Java has no (fast) API to examine the desktop for changes. If you can live with 1 fps or less, you can use the `Robot` API :-)

So all you can get is a VNC client/viewer. I experimented a bit with [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/) because it's free and the sources are available.

Comment: but no more current releases for linux, just windows =(

Comment: The 2.6.2 Java viewer (included in the Windows release) works on Linux. And you can use `Xvnc` as a server on Linux.

Comment: just the viewer, I need full server + client including source code

Comment: I know what you need but you won't get it. It's not possible to write a server in Java.

Comment: sure? https://github.com/danielgomezrico/Remote-Control  "This version contain a server (in java) "

Comment: Do you see a place in the code where it gets/transmits the desktop image?

Comment: well there is for example in other projects the robot for taking screenshots ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I remember on a Java-Applet connectable to RealVNC, but it wasnt opensource, the compiled sources are obfuscated so i cant uncompile.

You may be able to ask for the Source.

Take a look at http://www.realvnc.com/products/vnc/documentation/4.0/win/java

Java is an high level programming language, VNC is programmed in **Low-Level** Programming language. You may be able to find a Solution with **jni**-combination of Java and any other low-level Programm!

But not in plain java.

Comment: well its just the viewer, need server and client / viewer if possible