# how can we develop screen mirroning of android device to PC?Something like mobizen application

Tags: android, usb, screen, mirror, mirroring

I want to develop an PC application which helps to mirror a android device through USB and also control the device through PC.

Please tell me is this possible?
If yes then please give some input for this requirement!

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible with a rooted android device, due to the fact that no application can send "touch" events to other applications (it would be an obvious security flaw). You could, however, have the user control JUST the application via their computer.

Comment: i did not understand what you meant by "You could, however, have the user control JUST the application via their computer". can you please emphasize.

Comment: Okay so you are trying to make it so that you can send commands to android via your computer, right? Well you'll need an application on the android side that connects to the computer as well, right? What I'm saying is that the android side application WILL NOT be able to send "touch" commands to any application other than itself without being rooted.

Comment: okay.I have rooted my device,can you please give me what can be done next to do this above requirement.

Answer (score 0):

this is possible with a *VNC server*

it displays the screen of your android on the pc via a VNC connection (Virtual Network Computing) and you can control the android with mouse, touchpad,...

see for example *droidVNCserver*, the git is in https://github.com/oNaiPs/droidVNCserver (device has to be rooted)

http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/control-android-from-pc

Comment: is there any way where we can do this without rooting the device?

Comment: VMLite VNC server seems not to have root requirement but it is not free on google play. on https://brianaberle777.wordpress.com/android-vnc-server-without-root/ is an instruction how to use droidVNCserver without root i do not know if this works

Comment: when i import this  [link](https://github.com/oNaiPs/droidVNCserver) into android studio it is asking for a NDK.may i know which NDK should i use.Is it the one given by google or is it custom NDK.If i have to use custom NDK then where can i find it in the that link.

Comment: NDK means Native Development Kit . droidVNC server uses native functions. native functions are low-level and hardware-dependent, meaning it matters on low levels on what cpu your android is running and what other devices are attached to the cpu (cameras,...). So with NDK is meant the google NDK but you have to know in detail the hardware of your smartphone to write working code... and the NDK is in C

Comment: Is there any way we can do this without customizing OS,because my requirement says that we need to get control of the different android devices to PC without doing any changes to the android devices.

Comment: VMLite VNC server does not require root or any changes to the OS. for VMLite is no souce code available and you have to start the server externally after every reboot of android . when using the NDK you do not change the OS. the NDK uses JNI (Java Native Interface) that links high-level java to low-level C. for writing a vnc server in java see http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/14198899/java-based-opensource-vnc-application-or-library